# Does Jenkins support Xcode integration

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build-automation

Has anyone used Jenkins in Xcode for code management and automated deployment ? If yes, how can it be integrated ? How does automated deployment work with Jenkins ? Went through the [**documentation**](https://jenkins.io/doc/) but didn't get much idea.
I went through the [**Jenkins plugins for iOS**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-iOSdevelopment) but not clear if we can publish the build to AppStore using any plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "Jenkins in Xcode for code management" seems not fully correct. Because Jenkins server is for CI, in which we config it (create a job) that will fetch the source code from your repository (SVN, GIT), then compile it and run, probably execute your unit tests, UI automation tests or code coverage tool.

Based on your schedule, Jenkins server will automatically start its job or is triggered whenever there is a change in your repo (anybody commits the code for example).

The tool you mentioned which in Xcode is probably XCode Bots, the built-in CI tool. 
In order to set up, firstly, you have to install and config XCode server. After that, connecting your server with your repositories. Secondly, creates a bot with your customize configuration and run it.

In my opinion in term of Jenkins and Xcode comparison, I would say that it depends on what tools or add-in functions that you want to set up for your CI server. Jenkins has many plugins might helpful like check style, measure code coverage while Xcode bot still having some limitation.
This document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ for your further reference.

I hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: Great help. Thanks. Can Jenkins/ Xcode bot be used for automated deployment to AppStore ? If so, which plugin ?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, however, what I have done is that deploying the build via beta testing. If you are using Jenkins, you need to config your job with the distribution certificate, XCode plugin, then distribute the ipa binary and deploy through TestFlight, however, you need to run some custom scripts . if you are using XCode bot, it would be easier.

Comment: Forgot this one, you can refer to this article about Jenkins http://blog.zymr.com/jenkins-integration-with-ios

Answer (score 2):

We are using a Jenkins Server for Continuos Integration, by fetching the source from an SVN Server when the Jenkins is triggered by Commits to this repositories.

But, to be serious, i wouldn't recommend the jenkins... i'd rather use xcode server/bots to get rid of all the hassle with the jenkins...

Comment: Not clear about your second point. Are you recommending Jenkins or Xcode server ?

Comment: I DO NOT recommend. Sorry for the typo! :-)

Answer (score 1):

fastlane is a tool for iOS and Android developers to automate tedious tasks like generating screenshots, dealing with provisioning profiles and releasing your application.
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

xctool is a replacement for Apple's xcodebuild that makes it easier to test iOS and Mac products. It's especially helpful for continuous integration.
https://github.com/facebook/xctool

Comment: Thanks. And how about Jenkins ? :)

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Jenkins.md.  It is easy to integrate with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called [xcpretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty), you can use it to output `JUnit` format test result, then use `Jenkins JUnit Plugin` to show the result.

- Install xcpretty

```
    gem install xcpretty
```

- Use xcpretty to create junit format xml file

```
    xcodebuild test ... | xcpretty --report junit --output [path_to_save]/unit_test_result.xml
```

- Then this `unit_test_result.xml` can be used to report by Jenkins JUnit Plugin